# Go-CD - How do you stop generating artifacts when JUNIT or JASMINE or Regression Test fails in Go-CD

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment, go-cd

We are actively using GO-CD. We get JUNIT JASMINE and other results, how ever the build artifacts are always published by go-cd which is picked by other agents to perform automated deployment.
We wish to set percentage value markers for JUNIT JASMINE etc, and if the observed value is lesser than the % marker, then we are interested to make go-cd not publish artifacts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally after report creation another task kicks in which verifies the report results.

It could be e.g. a grep command inside a shell script looking for the words fail or error in the XML report files. As soon as the task finishes with a return code not equal to 0, GoCD considers the task to be failed.

Same applies for the percentage marker, a task is needed which calculates the percentage and then provides an appropriate return code. 0 when percentage goal is met or exceeded and different from 0 when the goal has not been met. This one could also be implemented as a custom task such as a shell script evaluating the reports.

The pipeline itself can be configured to not publish any artifacts in case the task fails or errors.